# Find cell in position relative to address in other cell

Tags: excel

Is there a function I can put in cell `A2` that will return whatever is in the cell below whatever cell is written in `A1`?

So for example, if `A1` contains `=B35` then `A2` will return the value contained in cell `B36` and if I change `A1` to `=C17` then `A2` will now contain whatever is in `C18`?

I've been trying to use combinations of `indirect()`, `offset()` and `address()`, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your not wanting to do anything more complex than offsetting a single cell reference you could mix in a little VBA.

In a new module:

```
Public Function tFormula(ByVal Target As Range) As String
    tFormula = Mid(Target.FORMULA, 2)
End Function
```

B1 = "=C1"

C2 = "Hello"

A1 = "=Offset(tFormula(B1),1,0)"

Offset(tFormula(B1),1,0) = "Hello"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done quite like you want.  The closest I can come is putting the "target" address in a cell, e.g., in this picture A2 just contains the string "b3".  You can then point indirect functions at that.  So the formula in D2, for the value of the cell below B3, is:

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(A2),1,0)`

[image]

Comment: +1. If there was actually a "=" portion then this could be stripped out with `SUBSTITUTE`

Comment: Thanks Dave, I mean @brettdj. If you mean the "=" at the begin of formula could be Substituted out, I don't know how. That was the first thing I attempted, as it would make the whole thing easier, but short of doing it in VBA, I don't see how.

Comment: I agree - I was thinking of a string such as `'=B5` rather than a true formulae. Which on second thought is very unlikely

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved this one. In Excel 2013, My problem is similar to yours:

`E107` contains `=A100`, I want `E108` to return the value contained in cell `B100`, so if I change `E107` to `=A101` then `E108` will now contain whatever is in `B101`.

My solution:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(E107),2),1))+1)&RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(E107),LEN(FORMULATEXT(E107))-2))
```

I'm getting the text of the formula in the cell with `FORMULATEXT` and applying ASCII operations with `CODE` and `CHAR` to add up to `A`, so that it becomes `B`, and then returning the value with `INDIRECT`. Some string operations needed, with `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions.